# Can I password protect a Publisher file?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, microsoft-publisher

I was asked ealier this week if it was possible to password protect a Microsoft Office 2007 Publisher document. I was under the impression that it would be like protecting a Word document, by going to Office > Save As > Word Document > Tools > General Options and creating a password to modify, like shown below. This also works for Excel documents.

[image]

However, in Publisher 2007 the option is not there. The only option under "Tools" is "Map network drive".

We overcame the issue as saving as a PDF and distributing that, but is there a way to do what we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

[This](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/password-protect-documents-workbooks-and-presentations-HA010148333.aspx) applies to:

- Access 2007
- Excel 2007
- InfoPath 2007
- OneNote 2007
- PowerPoint 2007
- Publisher 2007
- Visio 2007
- Word 2007

but only gives protection information for:

- Excel 2007
- PowerPoint 2007
- Word 2007

Looking at 2010, it doesn't appear to have changed. The only option would be an external program, such as zip with password protection, but publisher itself doesn't support password protection.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't password protect, you can make the file "Read Only" by going to the file properties by right clicking on the file. At the bottom click Read Only and then click Apply.

[image: Screenshot of Properties panel]